# Javascript Onload expected object error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting "scrollingMsg" is undefined. It's not the cause though; it was functioning before I started doing the validSalesAmt() function. Beside that, not sure if this will help find the bug, but clicking the fields in the form gave an error saying that function wasn't defined. Please, no recommendations 'you can do it this way instead' because this is an assignment for school that has to be done as is in the textbook.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Chapter 10 Shoreline State Bank</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var adMsg = " **Did you know some used cars can have 100% loan value? Ask for details! **"
var beginPos = 0

function scrollingMsg()
    {
        msgForm.scrollingMsg.value=adMsg.substring(beginPos,adMsg.length)+adMsg.substring(0,beginPos)
        beginPos=beginPos+1
        if (beginPos>adMsg.length)
            {
                beginPos=0
            }
        window.setTimeout("scrollingMsg()",200)
    }

var salesAmt
var loanAmt
var loanRate
var loanYears

function validSalesAmt()
    {
        var salesAmt=parseInt(homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.value,10)
        if(isNaN(salesAmt)||(salesAmt <= 0))
        {
            alert("The sales price is not a valid number!")
            homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.value = ""
            homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.focus()
        }
        else
        {
            var downPmtAmt=parseInt(homeLoanForm.DownPayment.value, 10)

        if(isNaN(downPmtAmt)||(downPmtAmt<=0)||(downPmtAmt>salesAmt))
            {
                alert("The down payment should be greater than 0 and less than the sales amount!")
                homeLoanForm.DownPayment.value=""
                homeLoanForm.DownPayment.focus()
            }
        else
            {
                loanAmt = salesAmt-downPmtAmt
                homeLoanForm.LoanAmount.value=loanAmt
                homeLoanForm.Rate.focus()
            }
        }
    }

function CalcLoanAmt()
    {
        loanRate=parseFloat(homeLoanForm.Rate.value)
        if (isNaN(loanRate) || (loanRate <= 0))
            {
                alert("The interest rate is not a valid number!")
                homeLoanForm.Rate.value=""
                homeLoanForm.Rate.focus()
            }
        else
            {
                loanYears=homeLoanForm.Years.value
                if (isNaN(loanYears) || (loanYears < 1 || loanYears >30))
                    {
                        alert("Please select a valid number from the list (10,15,20, or 30)!")
                        homeLoanForm.Years.selectedIndex = 0
                        homeLoanForm.Years.focus()
                    }
                else
                    {
                        var monthlyPmtAmt = monthlyPmt(loanAmt,loanRate,loanYears)
                        homeLoanForm.Payment.value=dollarFormat(monthlyPmtAmt.toString())
                    }

            }       
    }

function monthlyPmt(loanAmt,loanRate,loanYears)
    {
        var interestRate = loanRate/1200
        var Pmts = loanYears*12
        var Amnt - loanAmt * (interestRate/(1-(1/Math.pow(1+interestRate,Pmts))))
        return Amnt.toFixed(2)
    }

function dollarFormat(valuein)
    {
        var formatValue= ""
        var formatDollars= ""
        formatAmt = valuein.split(".",2)
        var dollars = formatAmt[0]
        var dollarLen = dollars.length
        if (dollarLen > 3)
            {
                while (dollarLen > 0)
                    {
                        tempDollars = dollars.substring(dollarLen - 3,dollarLen)
                        if(tempDollars.length == 3)
                            {
                                formatDollars = ","+tempDollars+formatDollars
                                dollarLen = dollarLen - 3
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                formatDollars = tempDollars+formatDollars
                                dollarLen = 0
                            }
                    }
                if(formatDollars.substring(0,1) == ",")
                    {
                        dollars = formatDollars.substring(1,formatDollars.length)
                    }
                else
                    dollars = formatDollars
            }
        var cents = formatAmt[1]
        var formatValue="$"+dollars+"."+cents+
        return formatValue
    }

function popUpNotice()
    {
        open("chapter10-1notice.html","noticeWin","width-520,height=330")
    } 

function copyRight()
    {
        var lastModDate = document.lastModified
        var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)
        displayDateLast.innerHTML="<h6>Copyright&copy; Shoreline State Bank"+"<br />This document was last modified "+lastModDate+".</h6>"
    }
//-->
</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.align-center {
    text-align:center;
}

table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.block {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.center-div {
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.header-text {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.center-items {
    text-align: center;
}

.right-align {
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.left-align {
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#displayDateLast {
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

-->
</style>
</head>

<body onLoad="scrollingMsg(); popUpNotice(); copyRight();">

<div class="center-div">
  <p class="center-items"><img src="chapter10-1banner.jpg" alt="banner" /></p>
</div>
<div class="center-div">
<form id="msgForm">
    <p style="text-align:center">
    <input type="text" name="scrollingMsg" size="25" /></p>
</div>
<p style="text-align:center; font-size:16; font-weight:bold;">Home Mortgage Loan Payment Calculator</p>
<p class="block"><strong>Directions: </strong>Enter the agreed selling price, press the tab key, enter the down payment and press the tab key. The loan amount will be calculated automatically. Then enter the interest rate and the number of years for the loan and click the Calculate button.</p>
<div class="center-div">
<form id="homeLoanForm" method="post">
  <table>
        <tr>
           <td class="right-align">
              <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Sales Price:
           </td> 
           <td class="align-left"><input type="text" name="SaleAmount" size="9"  /> 
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="right-align">
             <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Down Payment in Dollars
          </td>
          <td class="align-left"><input name="DownPayment" type="text" id="DownPayment" size="9" onBlur="validSalesAmt()" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="right-align">
             <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Loan Amount
          </td>
             <td class="align-left"><input name="LoanAmount" type="text" id="LoanAmount" size="9" />          
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="right-align">
              <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Interest Rate (e.g. 5.9):
          </td>
           <td class="align-left"><input name="Rate" type="text" id="Rate" size="5" maxlength="5" /> 
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="right-align">
              <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Number of Years:
           </td>
           <td><select name="Years" id="Years">
             <option value="0">Select Number of Years</option>
             <option value=10>10</option>
             <option value=15>15</option>
             <option value=20>20</option>
             <option value=30>30</option>
           </select></td> 
      </tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="right-align">
             <input name="button" type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="CalcLoanAmt()"/>
           </td>
           <td class="align-left">
             <input name="Reset" type="reset" />
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="right-align">
              <span style="font-weight:bolder;">Monthly Payment:</span>
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="Payment" id="Payment" value=" " size="12" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="align-center">
             <span style="color:#cc0000; font-size:12px;">* Indicates a required field.</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
<div id="displayDateLast">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you limit the code to the area that has the problem?

Comment: if you combine all the answers you might get close to fixing this. just reading over your code shows quite a few syntax errors. go over it again, make sure you verify EVERY line

Comment: http://www.jslint.com/. It may help you along

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

when the browser finds a syntax-error in a `<script>` he will discard the entire script-code within this script.

a simple demonstration:

```
<body onLoad="foo();bar();foobar();">

<script type="text/javascript">

  var a + b;//syntax-error, similar to line 86 in your script

  //this will not run because this script has been discarded
  //because of the syntax-error above
  function bar(){
    alert('bar works');
  }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  //this will run because here is no syntax-error,
  //the function is available 
  function foo(){
    alert('foo works');
  }

  //although this function is available too this will not run
  //because of the error forced by the call of bar()
  function foobar(){
    alert('foobar works'); 
  }
</script>

</body>
```

That's why the function `scrollingMsg` will be unknown, although there is no syntax-error within this function, because there are multiple syntax-errors in this script, fix them.

Comment: while these syntax errors will break the script, there are numerous others. I wouldn't venture as far as correting the script for the OP since this is a homework assignment.

Comment: I love this community! You answer is perfect for the question, now. I hope the OP sees it that way.